# Can't add values/parameters to Firebase Remote Config

Tags: firebase, firebase-remote-config

I'm having some issues with adding values to `Firebase Remote Config`. Is there something that I'm missing?

I add the parameter and value, but when I look at the JSON it is of the wrong format.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you're having problems working with the Firebase Console, contact Firebase support for assistance.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: The default value that you provide is just a string, it's not a valid JSON, so when you open the JSON editor, it shows error.

Answer (score 0):

Choose to store a string instead of a JSON, which remote config allows.

BUT if you need a JSON, you must follow the proper format. JSON is a way to structuring a dataset in order to retrieve the data stored inside it later. JSON files have a specific syntax you are not following.

The fundamental building blocks to a JSON file is the key value pair—an identifier (the key) and the data you'll need to reach (the value), such as `"color" : "blue"`. If you know the key, you'll be able to get the value from the JSON.

A simple JSON with only one level:

```
{
    "color" : "blue"
}
```

You could add more colors with commas and new lines:

```
{
    "color" : "blue",
    "secondaryColor" : "red",
    "accentColor" : "yellow"
}
```

But let's say you had a website and wanted to indicate this colors only apply to the first page. You could 'nest' a JSON within the JSON by letting the VALUE of one of your key value pairs be the next hierarchical layer in the JSON, like this:

```
{
    "firstPage" : {
        "color" : "blue",
        "secondaryColor" : "red",
        "accentColor" : "yellow"
    },
    "secondPage" : {
        "color" : "green",
        "secondaryColor" : "orange",
        "accentColor" : "purple"
    },
}
```

This is called a nested JSON. It's two JSON objects within a JSON object.

In your example, you need to follow the JSON structure.

```
{
    "test" : "Firebase Remote Config"
}
```

[Learn about JSONs here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp).